# CodingBat Python Warmup2 front_times

Tags: python, string

**Here are the instructions on CodingBat:**

*Given a string and a non-negative int n, we'll say that the front of the string is the first 3 chars, or whatever is there if the string is less than length 3. Return n copies of the front;*

**My code:**

```
def front_times(str, n):
    return n * (str[0:3])
```

**Solution Code**

```
def front_times(str, n):
  front_len = 3
  if front_len > len(str):
    front_len = len(str)
  front = str[:front_len]

  result = ""
  for i in range(n):
    result = result + front
  return result
```

Both solutions work. Is there any reason to use the long form code in the solution? Is there a time that my shorter code won't work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, your code works exactly the same and is a nice simple, pythonic solution. Sometimes tutorial code is longer and more verbose than needed so it is clearer what the code is doing. But nice solution!

Comment: Note that 0 for the slice start value is the default so you could write `str[:3]`.

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus What do you mean? `'a'[:3]` returns `'a'`.

Comment: @ NOhs, sorry I was wrong.

Comment: Well done - see [this repl](https://repl.it/repls/DelayedSoulfulNotifications) to play with validity/performance checking - it looks like your solution is also more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for all the great replies and encouragement. I've dabbled in code before (mostly just HTML), but am really trying to learn Python and really dive into this world. I'm just starting, but it's been fun and challenging. Thanks again!